# Prevent Single Quotation Marks when Mysql Escape()

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, code-injection

```
var user = "hi"; //this info comes from the client in reality
console.log(user); //user

user = client.escape(user); //cient being a Mysql client
console.log(user); //'user'
```

Then when I insert into the database, the single quotation marks are still there.
And when I select it, there are still there...

Is there a way to make sure the client isn't doing injection stuff and at the same time, not add single quotes in the database? Or at least a way to remove them, such as unescape()?

I can use `user.slice(1,-1)` but that doesn't seem the right way to do it.

Note: I'm using Nodejs.

Comment: What mysql driver are you using? How are you querying the database?

Comment: Yes. I'm using 'client = require('mysql').createConnection(...)' on a Nodejs server.

Comment: I guess you're using [this one](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql) then. But I wondered how do you do the insert? `connection.query('INSERT INTO x SET user = ' + user, callback)` or `connection.query('INSERT INTO x SET user = ?', user, callback)`? The problem you're describing suggests that you have escaped the value twice, so please show the code you're using.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue, using `connection.escape`.

Answer (score 0):

so I am guessing you are using the node-mysql driver, and your error is that you attempted a query of the form

```
client.query('SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE userName = ?', user, function(err, result){
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

and your error from the query was looking something like

```
check your syntax around 'user_inputted_username''' on line x
```

and in such a case, Andreas Hultgren has the right answer; you've simply escaped the value twice. I know because his suggestion just solved my issue, which was that which I just described. Simply provide the unescaped user input as your argument to be escaped by the ? and .query() does the escaping for you.

Comment: The OP asked for a code sample. You just said this other person is right despite not showing how to actually double escape.